# Accessing value of progressEvent for progress bar from axios to set state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-state

I have two files - one of which is the common file that includes the logic for `PUT`request using axios. Another file includes the component that has `progress bar` which gets updated based on the value of `progressEvent` from `onUploadProgress` method. I would like to set state for `setUploadPercentage` with the current value that is emitted. But I am having a hard time in refactoring my code to access this value in my class component `FileUpload`. Any help would be appreciated.

1. File with axios request logic :-

```js
export function putData(formData) {
  return axios.put('/update', formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    onUploadProgress : (progressEvent) => {
        return parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total))
    },
  });
}
```

2. File with the component :-

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { putData } from "../../services/clientService";
import Progress from "../common/progress";

const FileUpload = () => {
  const [uploadPercentage, setUploadPercentage] = useState(0);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    // trying to use progressEvent value to update the value of uploadPercentage from response
    const res = await putData(formData);
  };

  return <Progress percentage={uploadPercentage} />;
};

export default FileUpload;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would pass `setUploadPercentage` as callback to `putData` and use it like that:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);

  // Pass a setUploadPercentage as callback here
  putData(formData, { onUploadProgress: setUploadPercentage )
    .then((response) => { 
      console.log(response);
    });
};
```

```
export function putData(formData, { onUploadProgress }) {
  return axios.put('/update', formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    onUploadProgress : (progressEvent) => {
      const progress = parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total));
      // Update state here
      onUploadProgress(progress);
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pass in a callback handler into the putData method that can receive the event instead.

```
export function putData(formData, handleUploadProgress = ()=>{}) {
  return axios.put('/update', formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    onUploadProgress : handleUploadProgress,
  });
}
```

Then your component could be:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { putData } from "../../services/clientService";
import Progress from "../common/progress";

const FileUpload = () => {
  const [uploadPercentage, setUploadPercentage] = useState(0);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
      // trying to use progressEvent value to update the value of uploadPercentage from response
      /* I think you need to remove this line for the rendering to progress, but maybe not.
        const res = await putData(formData);
      */ 
    putData(formData, (progressEvent) => {
      const percentage= parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total));
      setUploadPercentage(percentage);
      return percentage; // Because you were returning the percentage before.
    });
  };

  return <Progress percentage={uploadPercentage} />;
};

export default FileUpload;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before, I make progress bar with onUploadProgress event.

this is my example code as below.

```
import React from 'react';
import Progress from 'react-progressbar';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progress: 0,
      uploadFile: null,
    }
  }
  onChangeFile = (event) => {
    this.setState({ uploadFile: event.target.files[0] })
  }

  onUpload = () => {
    const config = {
      onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
        let { progress } = this.state;
        progress = (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100;
        this.setState({ progress });
      }
    }

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.state.uploadFile);
    axios.post('http://your_backend_url/api/v1/upload', formData, config).then(res => {
      if (res.data.status == 200) {
        console.log("done: ", res.data.message);
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("error: ", err.message);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Progress completed={this.state.progress} />
        <input type="file" onChange={this.onChangeFile} />
        <button onClick={this.onUpload.bind(this)} >File Upload</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you as well.
Best Regards.